# Php : Do mathematical operation on string

Tags: php

I have an value in variable like below

```
$game = "4+9";
```

I want it to echo 13 , How to convert it to integer.

note : I get value of 4+9 from file_get_contents,

Comment: Some creativity ? `echo array_sum(explode('+', '4+9'));`

Comment: Though it is possibe to evaluate that 'term' you should try all you can _not_ to do that. Is is a clear sign of bad application design if you _have to_ evaluate such a term stored inside a string.

Comment: try use echo eval("return 4+9;");

Comment: why -1 ? I really get angry u know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$strings = explode("+", "4+9");
$value = intval($strings[0]) + intval($strings[1]);
echo $value
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo array_sum(explode("+",$game));
```

Comment: with yours i get 7+3 = 0 ?

Comment: you must have something else going on.  You say that you are getting 4+9 from file_get_contents... Is there more content coming in from the file into the $game variable?

Comment: its random addition between 2 numbers , if its 13 , i can echo "13";

Comment: @VishnuSimbu `echo array_sum(explode('+','7+3'));` works for me - I quickly tested it on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ - you may need to check that `$game` is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just dealing with addition, you could split the string by the plus-operator and add the numbers.

```
$numbers = explode('+', $game);
$result = 0;
foreach($numbers as $num) {
    $result += intval($num);
}
```

This would get complex pretty quickly as you start adding other operators, brackets etc.

You could use `eval` to just run the text content of the file, but you have to be sure nobody will put anything nasty in the file.

Comment: Oh I answered the same, but any specific reason for using `intval` here?

Comment: I guess it is belt and braces really. `+=` in PHP is a mathematical operator, but quite a few languages I use infer whether `+=` is a mathematical or string operator based on types so I'm used to making the types explicit to avoid accidental concatenation ("49" in this case) - although in PHP that shouldn't happen. Also, if the string passed in was invalid, this would be more forgiving: `"4a+9b"`. This could be changed to `floatval` if non-integer numbers were anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

You should break your string into series of substrings with a loop. If you are 100% sure it's only "+" operator, then you can have simple code like this:

$data = explode('+', $game);

echo $data[0]+$data[1];

But what will happen if you have -, / or * ?

Also, you can always use eval() function, but this highly not recommended because of security issues.

Comment: What if there were 3 numbers, or only 1?

Comment: @SteveFenton Well, as I wrote - he should use loop. Example I've sent is just the easiest case and it is completely wrong solution.